# Python numpy: sum every 3 rows (converting monthly to quarterly)

Tags: python, numpy

I have a set of one-dimensional numpy arrays with monthly data. I need to aggregate them by quarter, creating a new array where the first item is the sum of the first 3 items of the old array, etc.

I am using this function, with x =3 :

```
def sumeveryxrows(myarray,x):
     return([sum(myarray[x*n:x*n+x]) for n in range( int(len(myarray)/x))])
```

It works, but can you think of a faster way? I profiled it, and 97% of the time is spent doing __getitem__

Comment: Aside: if you're working with timeseries data you're probably going to find it much more convenient to use [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org) rather than bare numpy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use reshape (assuming your array has a size multiple of x):

```
sumeveryxrows = lambda myarray, x: myarray.reshape((myarray.shape[0] / x, x)).sum(1)
```

The above takes less than `.3s` on an array with `30000000` values:

```
>>> a = numpy.random.rand(30000000)
>>> cProfile.run('sumeveryxrows(a, 3)')
         8 function calls in 0.263 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.258    0.258 <stdin>:1(<lambda>)
        1    0.005    0.005    0.263    0.263 <string>:1(<module>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.258    0.258 _methods.py:31(_sum)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.263    0.263 {built-in method exec}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
        1    0.258    0.258    0.258    0.258 {method 'reduce' of 'numpy.ufunc' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'reshape' of 'numpy.ndarray' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.258    0.258 {method 'sum' of 'numpy.ndarray' objects}
```

Answer (score 1):

another solution may be

```
def sumeveryxrows(myarray, x):
  return [sum(myarray[n: n+x]) for n in xrange(0, len(myarray), x)]
```

This is for python 2.x. If your using python 3 replace xrange with range.
xrange uses an iterator rather than generating an entire list.
You can also specify a step. This removes the need to use multiplication.

Then of course there is always the non-python way to do it (specifically for 3).

```
def sumevery3rows(a):
  i = 0
  ret = []
  stop = len(a) - 2
  while i < stop:
    ret.append(a[i] + a[i+1] + a[i+2])
    i += 3
  if i != len(a):
    ret.append(sum(a[i:len(a)]))
  return ret
```

I don't know how well this performs, and an implementation for variable x would probably make any benefits of this solution non-existent.